# Picture shows in excel if a threshold is hit

Tags: excel, image

I am creating an excel spreadsheet to track sales quota.  I would like the spreadsheet to display a picture of fireworks when quota is hit.  I don't know that much about macros, but good with formulas but that doesn't seem to help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way that I know it can be done:

1) Paste the picture of the fireworks in a cell (say A1) in a separate (preferably hidden sheet). Make sure to resize the cell (or the picture) so that the picture completely fits inside cell A1.

2) Define a named formula, maybe named "fireworks", which goes like:

=IF([Your condition for the fireworks to show],INDIRECT("[cell in which firework pic is]"),INDIRECT("[any blank cell"))

like for eg:

=IF(Sheet1!$C$6=TRUE,INDIRECT("Sheet2!$a$1"),INDIRECT("Sheet1!$M$8"))

3) Go to 'Insert' tab, click Object, click bitmap image. If paint or any image editor opens up just close it, so it inserts a blank image/object into the sheet. This image will have "=EMBED("Paint.Picture","")" in the formula bar. Replace this with a reference to our named formula, like =fireworks

4) Resize and reposition this image/object. When the condition is satisfied, the pic should pop up.